# Ubuntu service - pq: password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, postgresql

I have an application running on Ubuntu server that's using PostgreSQL.

I can run the application's executable (as a non-root user) from the project's directory.

I have created a service for this application (`/etc/systemd/system/cineapi.service`), so that it starts automatically on reboot. The contents of this file are:

```
[Unit]
Description=cineapi

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
WorkingDirectory=/home/saurabh/projects/cineapi
ExecStart=/home/saurabh/projects/cineapi/cineapi.o

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When a reload the system daemon and start the service like:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service cineapi start
```

I'm getting an error:

```
pq: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

I dont understand why this is happening. I'm not using the "root" user anywhere in the application. It's `.env` file looks like

```
postgres://goapi:somepassword@MY_IPV4_ADDR:DB_PORT/cineapi
```

and is sourced at startup. I also have the following changes in:

- `/etc/postgresql/16/main/postgresql.conf`

  ```
  password_encryption = scram-sha-256
  ```
- `/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf`

  ```
  host    cineapi         goapi           MY_IPV4_ADDR            scram-sha-256
  ```
- DB user `goapi` has superuser privileges

  ```
  postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
  Role name |                         Attributes                         
  ----------+------------------------------------------------------------
  goapi     | Superuser, Create DB
  postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS
  ```

#### Logs

Postgres logs when executing the binary:

```
2024-02-24 18:42:31.053 PST [16433] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-02-24 18:42:36.817 PST [16433] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 60 buffers (0.4%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=5.737 s, sync=0.014 s, total=5.765 s; sync files=54, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=201 kB, estimate=201 kB; lsn=0/1A477E0, redo lsn=0/1A477A8
2024-02-24 18:43:39.173 PST [16573] goapi@cineapi LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer             #### ---------------- I stopped the executable ----------------- ####
```

Postgres logs when starting the application's system service

```
2024-02-24 18:37:31.024 PST [16432] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-02-24 18:38:28.926 PST [16473] root@root FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Comment: You've configured systemd to invoke the executable `/home/saurabh/projects/cineapi/cineapi.o`, but under which Linux user will it be invoked?

Comment: Looks like when `User` and `Group` are not mentioned in the service file, `root` gets selected by default. Since I'm able to run the executable directly with my user and group - `saurabh:saurabh`. So I've added `User=saurabh` and `Group=saurabh` to `cineapi.service`, I'm getting error: `saurabh@saurabh FATAL:  database "saurabh" does not exist`.

Comment: Could that new error be consistent with the command not reading the `.env` file you prepared?  (I'm not very familiar with `psql` so I might be mistaken to search in that particular direction)

Comment: I have `PGUSER`, `PGPASSWORD`, `PGHOST`, and `source ~/projects/cineapi/.env` at the end of my `.bashrc`. The former values correspond to what's set in the `.env` file. However, I'm not sure whether `.bashrc` sourcing this file is being applied to `/etc/systemd/system/cineapi.service`.

Comment: I don't think its consistent because of my config in `.bashrc`.

Comment: I think now the question is:  What part of the `cineapi.service` file tells systemd to invoke bash?

Comment: The service doesn't invoke bash at the moment. I though `cineapi.service` would run after `.bashrc` is sourced by Ubuntu. Looks like that's not happening. What the right way of doing this ?